# Why is my progress bar not progressing? Is it in a loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a progress bar so that as the lines are processed the bar goes up. I can't get it to work.

```py
import io
from datetime import datetime
from alive_progress import alive_bar

result = io.open("Edificado/edificadoResultadoSinPorBlancos.txt","w",encoding='utf-8',errors="surrogateescape")

start_time = datetime.now()
print(f"Empece en: {start_time}")

with io.open("Edificado/edificco.txt","r",encoding='utf-8',errors="surrogateescape" ) as f:
    data = len(f.readlines())
    with alive_bar(len(data)) as bar:
        for line in f:
            if '|' in line:
                line = line.replace("|","-")
            result.write(line)
            bar()
result.close()

end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duracion: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Comment: Your code can't work, `data = len()` then you do `len(data)`. Also you cant' read the file twice, one with readlines then `for line in f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read the file conten twice, one with `f.readlines()` and one with `for line in f` because the file descriptor is at the end

Do

```py
start_time = datetime.now()
print(f"Empece en: {start_time}")

with io.open("Edificado/edificco.txt","r",encoding='utf-8',errors="surrogateescape" ) as f, 
     io.open("Edificado/edificadoResultadoSinPorBlancos.txt","w",encoding='utf-8',errors="surrogateescape") as result:
    lines = f.readlines()
    with alive_bar(len(lines)) as bar:
        for line in lines:
            result.write(line.replace("|","-"))
            bar()
```

Also

- you were calling `len` twice, that couldn't work
- don't need to check for a character presence to replace it (about `|`)